# Splitting data and label into two separate columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a text file with lines like these:

A bunch of text, with commas, punctuations etc.,ham

The line always ends with ham or spam. How can I read a csv file containing data like this and store the first part of the text up to the last comma in a "name" field and the last bit as a "label" field (in the case above it will be:

```
  df["label"] = "ham", 
  df["name"] = 'A bunch of text, with commas, punctuations etc.'
```

Is there also a way to weed out text that is not specified the way I describe above? Say some line has no spam or ham at the end, I want to skip those. How can I use pandas.read_csv() to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Given this is your original data frame:

```
df

                                                Col1
0  A bunch of text, with commas, punctuations etc...
1                                 test,foo,.bar,spam
```

Use `df.str.rsplit`. Split on `,` once, and expand the result to two columns. `df.rename` will elegantly rename your columns.

```
df.Col1.str.rsplit(',', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0 : 'name', 1 : 'label' })

                                              name label
0  A bunch of text, with commas, punctuations etc.   ham
1                                    test,foo,.bar  spam
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this during the data import process. You will need to use regular expression as a separator. The expression is looking for the last comma in each line that is followed by something. The following should serve as a decent illustration:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

txt = u"A bunch of text, with commas, punctuations etc.,ham"

with io.StringIO(txt) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f,
                     sep=",(?=[^,]+$)",
                     header=None,
                     engine="python",
                     names=['name', 'label']))

print(df)
```

Should yield:

```
                                              name label
0  A bunch of text, with commas, punctuations etc.   ham
```

I hope this serves a purpose.